# Cognos 11 Analytics - Line Chart Color

Tags: business-intelligence, linechart, cognos, cognos-bi

In my Dashboard is a Line Chart with 4 Lines so I need them to have 4 different colors. But no matter how I change the color palette, only 2 (max 3) different colors are used.

How can I assign a different color to each line?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

[image: Color Dimensions]

[image: Color Palette]

Comment: The Dashboarding tool has been changing quickly.  What version of Cognos Analytics are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom palette with 4 colours, then click on the item you want the colour applied to, it usually takes.  I just tried this in an 11.1.7 install.

So in your case click on Actual 2019 on either the x or y axis.